# Custom Listview Layout not reflecting in output android

Tags: android, listview

I am designing a custom listview  layout , in that the xml part looks like desired output , but when I run this in the real device then it throws Error " Imageview Cannot be cast into Textview"

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="69dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:shadowColor="#585858"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20"
            android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="15dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_row"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"             
        android:src="@drawable/rings_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="KARTHIK.KOLANJI"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Facebook Friend"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:text=" days  left"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_days_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="36"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
        android:text="t u r n s"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:text="24"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Wednesday"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="(Anniversary)"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:text="Next birthday on : "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:text="Zodiac :  "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Sagittarius"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:text="7th, April 1990"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_name"
        android:text="9594080469"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="15dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20" 
        android:src="@drawable/aries"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's [Layout Image Link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/13056829804/)

Here's [Logcat screen shot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/13056829353/)

Error throwing line :

```
viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);
            viewHolder.txtTurnsAge=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);
            viewHolder.txtEventWeek=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_next_bd);
            viewHolder.txtNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_contact_number);
            viewHolder.txtBirthDay=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_birthdate);
            viewHolder.txtZodiac=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
            viewHolder.txtZodiacValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_zodiac);
            viewHolder.txtNextBD=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            viewHolder.txtDayRemainig=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
            viewHolder.txtTurnsAgeValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);
            viewHolder.thumbZodiacIcon= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            viewHolder.thumbEventIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
            viewHolder.thumbContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
```

Comment: check id's, if every thing look good, clean your project, uninstall from phone then install again

Comment: I already tried this solution .... not worked

Comment: in one place in your code, you try access to `ImageView` with `TextView` object, post code and logcat

Comment: Can you post your java code as well as error that you are getting in logcat.

Comment: the real problem is , while I try to adjust the view by drag and drop , it throws error ..what could be the solution

Comment: post logcat error and your code

Comment: In your xml file you have dropped your ImageView within TextView element So this error occurred. Show your logcat and code.

Comment: please indicate line 225 on CustomSimpleCursor

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan--- viewHolder.txtTurnsAge=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);

Comment: updated issues ..Can u please look in to this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412293/xml-layout-behaves-abnormal-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_empty"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="69dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#585858"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20"
        android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_row"
    android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
    android:src="@drawable/rings_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
    android:text="KARTHIK.KOLANJI"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_title_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Facebook Friend"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:text=" days  left"
    android:textColor="#996600"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_days_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04"
    android:text="36"
    android:textColor="#990000"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sub_title_category"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
    android:text="t u r n s"
    android:textColor="#996600"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:text="24"
    android:textColor="#990000"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
    android:text="Wednesday"
    android:textColor="#CC0000"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:text="Next birthday on : "
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
    android:text="Zodiac :  "
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
    android:text="Sagittarius"
    android:textColor="#CC0000"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
    android:text="7th, April 1990"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="13dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_name"
    android:text="9594080469"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="13dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView01"
    android:text="(Anniversary)"
    android:textColor="#787878"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView04"
    android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
    android:shadowDx="0.0"
    android:shadowDy="0.0"
    android:shadowRadius="20"
    android:src="@drawable/aries" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow.. great 90 % problem solved ... but in some listview item the zodiac icon overlaps on the zodian name AND days remainin get lightly shifted to left side  [Screen shot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/13057364814/)

Comment: The problem is because of that. you have to left some margin or you can manually shift textview from imageview. so you can get better output.

Comment: I am sorry to say , the icon got attached to "days remaining" textview , instead of that I require it to get attached to Zodiac name [  screen schot  ](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/13057286195/)

Comment: Ok then just give margin right 15dp or 20dp to your Icon

Comment: If days remaining is single digit like "2" ,then the textview gets shifted to left and if it is three digit like "365", then the layout looks good

Comment: Can u please look in to this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412293/xml-layout-behaves-abnormal-android

Answer (score 0):

I think in your adapter class somewhere you are doing like

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01)
```

It means you are casting ImageView to TextView object which should not be done.
Once check your code.