# xml layout behaves abnormal android

Tags: android

I am designing a custom listview , which hold many child view . In that there is two child views which behaves abnormal

1. if "turns" value is single digit, then view gets shifted to left hand side
2. I always wanted "zodia or stone " image icon to be always 3dip left margin to the "zodia or stone " textview value , so that value and image appears side by side with 3dip .But left margin is not working , hence I set to right margin

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="85dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#585858"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20"
        android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_row"
    android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
    android:src="@drawable/rings_icon" 
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_row"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
    android:text="KARTHIK.KOLANJI"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_title_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Facebook Friend"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:text=" days  left"
    android:textColor="#996600"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sub_title_category"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
    android:text="t u r n s"
    android:textColor="#996600"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:text="24"
    android:textColor="#990000"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
    android:text="Wednesday"
    android:textColor="#CC0000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
    android:text="Sagittarius"
    android:textColor="#CC0000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" 
    />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:text="(Anniversary)"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView04"
    android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
    android:shadowDx="0.0"
    android:shadowDy="0.0"
    android:shadowRadius="20"
    android:src="@drawable/scroll" 
    android:layout_marginRight="50dip"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_name"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image_arrow"
    android:text="9594080469"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
    android:text="7th, April 1990"
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtview_turns"
    android:text="Zodiac :  "
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview_days_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView04"
    android:text="36"
    android:textColor="#990000"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
    android:text="Birthday on : "
    android:textColor="#181818"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's [Screen Shot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/13151346644/)

Comment: is there is any other way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`?
I've found `RelativeLayout` to give wonky results with lots of children. (Especially when the content is added programatically) Try this instead:

`LinearLayout` < Container for the body of your content `Orientation.VERTICAL`

`LinearLayout` < New Row of Content `Orientation.HORIZONTAL`

For every new row of content, place it inside of the second `LinearLayout` and make it a child of the first.

I suspect your issues will disappear quickly.

Comment: If I change to linear layout , then my whole layout would be disturbed because every where I used RelativeLayout attribute

Comment: Sometimes it's sucks, but we've got to man up and do what's best for the application, even if that means rewriting huge sections of code. I'm sure you can find a way to do it with `RelativeLayout` but since you're adding the content dynamically, and you're having issues with content being displaced by the content generated, I really think you'll be better off with `LinearLayout`. It's up to you, and it may take an hour, but if your code is better for it, is it really a sacrifice?

Comment: yes, I understand , but what do u mean by " dynamically " ? . Its a drag and dropped view, not wrote by java code

Comment: from the screenshot, it looks like you're going to add those birthday reminders dynamically. Whether from a database or pulled from a web API, you're gonna have to use java to populate the "list_row".